Microsoft Fabric API : How to get the Connection id that is in DataPipeline
So there is a way to create a Fabric DataPipeline using API. Everything works fine, however in your JSON payload you need to specify the Connection id of all the connections in your Data Pipeline. The problem is that I cannot find a way on how to get this id using API. This connection is a Azure SQL Database connection. Is this a still missing feature?

Tried all API calls to get info on SQL connection, but non returned it. Also I cannot view it in OneLake Data Hub tab. This connection can only be viewed if you go to the Pipeline->Activity->Settings->Connections->More...

The API doesn't have that functionality. It very much make a basic pipeline, then have to go into it manually and do it

There is a way to get a list of Fabric connections using the Power BI API, but it is not well documented. I also believe that it requires a reference to the connection in an existing Fabric item for values to be returned, but I have not validated this.
Here's an example using Python and the sempy.fabric package included in Fabric notebooks to simplify authentication. Note that administrator rights on the Fabric tenant are required to leverage the initial PostWorkspaceInfo call.
import time
from sempy.fabric import PowerBIRestClient, get_workspace_id


def initiate_scan(client, workspace_id):
    # Initiate a scan for the given workspace ID.
    params = {"datasourceDetails": True, "lineage": True}
    body = {"workspaces": [workspace_id]}
    response = client.post(
        "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/workspaces/getInfo",
        json=body,
        params=params,
    )
    return response.json()["id"]


def check_scan_status(client, scan_id):
    # Check the status of the scan until it completes.
    status = None
    while status not in ["Failed", "Succeeded"]:
        if status:
            time.sleep(10)
        status = client.get(
            f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/workspaces/scanStatus/{scan_id}"
        ).json()["status"]
    return status


def get_scan_result(client, scan_id):
    # Fetch the scan result for the given scan ID.
    response = client.get(
        f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/workspaces/scanResult/{scan_id}"
    )
    return response.json().get("datasourceInstances")


def main():
    # Main function to initiate and check the scan, then print the results.
    client = PowerBIRestClient()
    workspace_id = get_workspace_id()

    try:
        scan_id = initiate_scan(client, workspace_id)
        scan_status = check_scan_status(client, scan_id)

        if scan_status == "Succeeded":
            data_sources = get_scan_result(client, scan_id)
            if data_sources:
                print(data_sources)
            else:
                print("No data sources returned.")
        else:
            print("Scan failed.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

You should also be able to get this information using Gateways - Get Datasources, but this request requires a gateway id and I haven't found a way to authenticate to the gateway for Cloud connections.
